# SqlException not caught in Winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, exception, try-catch

I got this code:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection sourceCnx = new SqlConnection(SOURCE_CONN_STRING))
    {
        sourceCnx.Open();
        SqlCommand sysCmd = sourceCnx.CreateCommand();
        sysCmd.CommandText = "My query";
        sysCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Throwing a message box informing that there is an error
}
```

I want to display a message when the user is no longer connected to the internet.
But when I debug my program without an internet connection, the program crashes with a SqlException. (The "catch" block does not catch the exception)

I tried to add `catch (SqlException) { // code }` before `catch (Exception)` but it doesn't work.
I still have an exception instead of a message displayed by the catch block.

I don't know what to do because if I create a method to test the internet connection (`try` to ping google.com) then return true if it's ok, it will be the same : I got an exception because of no internet connection.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is being thrown from within that `try` block?  A `catch` block will catch an exception.  (Side note: Your exception handling is ignoring useful information about the exception.  At the very least you should examine the type of exception, the error message, and the stack trace.  Throwing away information about the error will make fixing the error very difficult.)

Comment: Yea, Visual Studio told me that the line `sourceCnx.Open();` is the cause of the exception. I also tried to write `catch (Exception ex) { var excep = ex.GetType().FullName; }`but the catch block is not reached.

Comment: Are you just breaking on all exceptions when in debug mode?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry.. I am not fluent in english, please forgive me.

Comment: Is this option ticked? Debug menu -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Comment: This is the only try/catch block which does not catch the exception thrown.
I use others try/catch blocks for other situations and they catch the exception thrown.

Comment: Yep this is the only checkbox ticked. (CLR Exceptions)

Comment: When Visual Studio catches the exception, can you please expand the details and tell us the type of the exception? You say, visual studio tells you the line sourceCnx.Open is the statement the exception is thrown..

Comment: Also, there are 2 check-boxes there, Thrown and user-unhandled. Can you please confirm that only user-undhandled checkbox is checked for CLR Exceptions?

Comment: Here is the message when the exception is thrown : "_A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll_"

Comment: Then, it will definitely gets into the catch block. This means that you have the option CLR Exceptions - Thrown checked. +1 to DavidG if it is so.

Comment: In VS : Debug > Exceptions > There is only two columns : _Name_ and _Thrown_. And only one checkbox is ticked in the column _Thrown_ for the _Name_ "_Common Language Runtime Exceptions_".

Comment: Remove that checkbox and the exceptions will get to your catch block first. When unhandled, (no catch block and it goes all up to crash your app) then only to the debugger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94108/discussion-between-oguz-ozgul-and-hellcat8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your environment to always break when a CLR exception is thrown. You can leave it like that if you wish and press F5 to carry on execution of your program. Or you can turn this off (it is switched off by default):

Go to `Debug` menu, select `Exceptions` and ensure `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` is *not* checked.

[image]

Comment: It was checked but I canceled it. Now it successfully display the message but after that, Visual Studio wants me to press "Continue" to let my program continue. But even doing it, my program become indredibly slow to respond.

Comment: Continue on what line?

Comment: on a "**}**" after the catch block

Answer (score 1):

You might want to put the exception handing inside the using block, like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sourceCnx = new SqlConnection(SOURCE_CONN_STRING))
    {
        try
        {
            sourceCnx.Open();
            SqlCommand sysCmd = sourceCnx.CreateCommand();
            sysCmd.CommandText = "My query";
            sysCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            // This will catch any SQL Exceptions.
            // Use "throw;" if you want to rethrow the exception up the stack
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // This will catch any other exceptions.
            // Use "throw;" if you want to rethrow the exception up the stack
        }
    }
```

Assuming that you have actually replaced "My Query" with something specific to your scenario, the SqlException is most likely down to your machine not being able to see the SQL Server instance. Try pinging it...

Comment: Could you please tell us exactly what you are using for the CommandText, and also paste the details of the exception in your question?

Comment: Can we have SOURCE_CONN_STRING as well please? Forget the commandText - that's not your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection sourceCnx = new SqlConnection(SOURCE_CONN_STRING))
    {
        sourceCnx.Open();
        SqlCommand sysCmd = sourceCnx.CreateCommand();
        sysCmd.CommandText = "My query";
        sysCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
{
    MessageBox.Show("there was a sql issue");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("there was some other issue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the part of the catch code, you have to set a variable not? And after that take any of her property.

For example:

```
try
{
using (SqlConnection sourceCnx = new SqlConnection(SOURCE_CONN_STRING))
    {
        sourceCnx.Open();
        SqlCommand sysCmd = sourceCnx.CreateCommand();
        sysCmd.CommandText = "My query";
        sysCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
      //example 
      MessageBox.show(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: I did not understand what you wrote but I tried your code and the issue is still here.

Comment: We would only need to set a variable in the catch block if he intended to do something with the exception - which at this point he does not...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the BaseException

```
catch (Exception exp)
    {
        if (exp.GetBaseException() is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
        {
            var sqlException = exp.GetBaseException() as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;

            if (sqlException != null && sqlException.Number == 547)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
        //do something
    }
```